# Create routes for an admin area

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is causing me such grief!

Let's say I have a `story` class.

A normal user can create a story, view their stories and delete a story belonging to them.

An admin user can create a story, view **all** stories and delete **all** stories.

I want an admin area in the url structure:

```
/control_panel/stories # list all stories in the site
/control_panel/stories/new # create a new story
/control_panel/stories/:id # show, edit, update, delete story (via different request methods)
```

However, I also want users to have these routes:

```
/stories
/stories/new
/stories/:id
```

I have no idea how to implement this. Trying to create the routes has been a nightmare. This configuration:

```
  resources :stories
  scope '/control_panel' do
    resources :stories

  end
```

Is almost there:

```
   stories GET    /stories(.:format)                        stories#index
           POST   /stories(.:format)                        stories#create
 new_story GET    /stories/new(.:format)                    stories#new
edit_story GET    /stories/:id/edit(.:format)               stories#edit
     story GET    /stories/:id(.:format)                    stories#show
           PATCH  /stories/:id(.:format)                    stories#update
           PUT    /stories/:id(.:format)                    stories#update
           DELETE /stories/:id(.:format)                    stories#destroy
           GET    /control_panel/stories(.:format)          stories#index
           POST   /control_panel/stories(.:format)          stories#create
           GET    /control_panel/stories/new(.:format)      stories#new
           GET    /control_panel/stories/:id/edit(.:format) stories#edit
           GET    /control_panel/stories/:id(.:format)      stories#show
           PATCH  /control_panel/stories/:id(.:format)      stories#update
           PUT    /control_panel/stories/:id(.:format)      stories#update
           DELETE /control_panel/stories/:id(.:format)      stories#destroy
```

**However, where are my named routes for the control_panel routes?!** I expected:

`GET /control_panel/stories` to have the name `control_panel_stories` (like its corresponding non-namespaced routes `/stories)`,

`GET /control_panel/stories/new` to have the name `new_control_panel_story`

`GET /control_panel/stories/:id/edit` to have the name `edit_control_panel_story`

and

`GET /control_panel/stories/:id` to have the name `control_panel_story`

Instead I have no named routes!

## Questions:

- *I need guidance, so tell me what I should be doing. If any of the following are irrelevant just say!*
- How do I give my scoped routes names? If giving them names is impossible, how do I access them in the views?
- If I use `namespace :control_panel` instead of `scope 'control_panel'`, I get my named routes:

---

```
resources :stories
namespace :control_panel do
    resources :stories
end
```

gives me:

```
   control_panel_stories GET    /control_panel/stories(.:format)          control_panel/stories#index
                         POST   /control_panel/stories(.:format)          control_panel/stories#create
 new_control_panel_story GET    /control_panel/stories/new(.:format)      control_panel/stories#new
edit_control_panel_story GET    /control_panel/stories/:id/edit(.:format) control_panel/stories#edit
     control_panel_story GET    /control_panel/stories/:id(.:format)      control_panel/stories#show
                         PATCH  /control_panel/stories/:id(.:format)      control_panel/stories#update
                         PUT    /control_panel/stories/:id(.:format)      control_panel/stories#update
                         DELETE /control_panel/stories/:id(.:format)      control_panel/stories#destroy
```

---

- ...however, now they don't link to the same controller anymore! Gah! They now link to a stories controller that should be found at `app/controllers/control_panel/stories_controller.rb`
- **So does this mean I should be using two controllers to edit one resource? This appears to be where rails is pushing me. Every resource has an 'open' controller and a 'control_panel' controller. Is this the correct way to do it?**
- I just feel like it's a waste when the 'open' controller's actions are identical to the 'control_panel' controller's actions. However, is the DRY of having one controller offset by the sheer complexity of pushing admins and normal users through one controller? This is a simple example, but I can imagine it could get a lot lot trickier. *I hope this is the case :)*
- So what is the point of `scope`d routes then? They seem kind of pointless.
- Do you think a namespace should be created whenever you're creating an exclusive 'area' in your site? A 'forums' area, a 'users' area, and yes, an 'admin' area? This would help to keep controllers more organised.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
scope :path => 'control_panel', :as => 'control_panel' do
```

For example you want the admin to be able to destroy, but not a regular user:

```
def destroy
  return redirect_to(:back, :notice => 'You need to be admin to delete.') if current_user.regular?
  ...
end
```

Comment: Excellent! Helped with my short-term one-controller approach. However, could you look at my other questions so I can decide what will we best in the long term? I'm actually leaning more towards a two controller approach now...

Comment: why do you want double controllers? is it for permissions?

Comment: there are ways to handle different types of users in the same controller

Comment: Yes, it's for permissions. But you think I should go for 1 controller?

Comment: yes, you can handle permissions in one controller, let me put an example

Answer (score 1):

about routes sope and namespace, you should have a look at this [article](http://notahat.com/2014/02/05/scoping-rails-routes.html)

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. Just saying on this site it's advisable to write the answer, not just link to a site, incase that blog goes down or changes its URL structure and future users who arrive at this question don't know what you meant :)